# Schedule 40 strapping ideas

Tags: electrical, conduit, vinyl-siding

I have some schedule 40 conduit on the side of my house that was never really installed properly. The 2 inch conduit at least has an expansion joint in place, but does not have any strapping. The 3/4 inch conduit obviously needs expansion joints installed as well as strapping. The part I'm struggling with here is how to install the strapping and what strapping products I should use.

An idea that I am considering is the following:

- Use [Arlington's QuickLatch](https://aifittings.com/landing/quicklatch_series) products to secure the conduit to unistrut.
- Either use [Arlington's Mounting Block](https://www.aifittings.com/catalog/siding-mounting-blocks/non-metallic-mounting-blocks-for-siding/) or miter cut my own mounting block out of PVC and mount that to the siding.
- Secure the unistrut to the mounting block.
- Caulk around any penetrations in the siding.

Does this seem like a reasonable plan, or are there better alternatives available? Open to any and all suggestions...

[image: Conduit_1]
[image: Conduit_2]
[image: Conduit_3]
[image: Conduit_4]
[image: Conduit_5]

Comment: Apart from the fact that it should be schedule 80 for "protection from damage" the last picture demonstrates a clear "not done in a workmanlike manner" entirely apart form the lack of attachment and expansion joints. 

I give the inspector an F- as this should never have made it to this point with all those defects.

Comment: @Ecnerwal The best part is that the previous homeowner, who was a master electrician, is the one who created this mess.

Comment: Ah, the barefoot cobblers children and the code-violating Master Electrician's house?

Comment: Yup. Now what would you suggest aside from digging up concrete and replacing the conduit runs in their entirety?

Answer (score 5):

If you particularly want to use Unistrut it works quite well, but it's a moderately ugly look for a house, and usually not needed. I suppose Unistrut will help if you have no sheathing that will hold a screw and need to span studs to get screw purchase.

With sheathing that will hold a screw, some sort of filler (mine would be "stacks of galvanized washers," but a fitted block is probably nicer) and some plain 2-hole conduit straps screwed to the wall are entirely adequate for attachment.

Really fixing the conduit will be a project, unless your LAHJ actually doesn't require schedule 80 or for some reason does not consider this "exposed to damage" as most areas do or would. Even then, the smaller conduits need offset bends to not look like a drunken skunk installed them off-kilter.

If schedule 80 is, as expected, called for here, you'd be pulling the wires back or out, cutting the conduit above ground level enough to take a coupling, transitioning to schedule 80, installing expansion joints (those are normally fairly low on the wall, not where the one you have is) and then strapping to the wall above the expansion joint (so the pipe from the ground into the expansion joint is NOT held by a strap on the house, and the expansion joint can move.) The smaller conduits would then go to offset bends (5, 7, 10, or 15 degrees, back to back) so they come up vertically, move sideways, and then come up vertically (or at an angle matching the present sloppy angle, I guess - in which case that would be the upper part of the offset) into the LBs. Those can be heat-formed in PVC conduit with care (so a single piece can be heat-formed to have the bends required, rather than having to glue up a bunch of bought bends.)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like theses conduits are less than 1 inch too short.

Perhaps you can dig dig up the near end and lift this end of the horizontal run a bit to close the gap.

Probably the ditch was not prepared correctly and the bedding for the conduit has sunk.

while you're at it it may be possible to shove them sideways so that they are vertical too.